# Basic Inheritance in Java

Tags: java, oop, inheritance

I'm currently learning and working on an exercise for class. I'm able to get a printout that resembles what I need, but the data isn't populating with test inputs. Name comes back null, Age: 0 and ID: 0.

Here's the scenario:

Assign courseStudent's name with Smith, age with 20, and ID with 9999. Use the printAll member method and a separate println statement to output courseStudents's data. Sample output from the given program:

**Name: Smith, Age: 20, ID: 9999**

```java
// ===== Code from file PersonData.java =====
public class PersonData {
   private int ageYears;
   private String lastName;

   public void setName(String userName) {
      lastName  = userName;
   }

   public void setAge(int numYears) {
      ageYears = numYears;
   }

   // Other parts omitted

   public void printAll() {
      System.out.print("Name: " + lastName);
      System.out.print(", Age: "  + ageYears);
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file StudentData.java =====
public class StudentData extends PersonData {
   private int idNum;

   public void setID(int studentId) {
      idNum = studentId;
   }

   public int getID() {
      return idNum;
   }
}
// ===== end =====

// ===== Code from file StudentDerivationFromPerson.java =====
public class StudentDerivationFromPerson {
   public static void main (String [] args) {
      StudentData courseStudent = new StudentData();

      courseStudent.printAll();
      System.out.println(", ID: " + courseStudent.getID());

   }
}
// ===== end =====
```

I'm sure that I'm overlooking something simple, but I'm not sure what. My code is the just the last few lines:

```java
courseStudent.printAll();
System.out.println(", ID: " + courseStudent.getID());
```

Comment: You would need to set some values via your _setters_, eg `courseStudent.setID(9999)`

Comment: This is Java. Your question title asks about JavaScript. They are not the same thing.

Comment: You can have a look @ https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://dzone.com/articles/java-getter-and-setter-basics-common-mistakes-and&ved=2ahUKEwjzo7G6jOLpAhXjxzgGHQnEBcgQFjAQegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1-lNp4C9Xy28VE4Hg_GqB8&cshid=1591065480913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you haven't tried to assign the args into the instance **courseStudent** that you just initiated. You can try this and see if this works:

```
      // Assumming your input is in this form : <name> <age> <student_id>
      // For example: Adam 19 4000
      StudentData courseStudent = new StudentData();

      // We get the args and convert them with the appropriate types
      String name = args[0];
      int age = String.parseInt(args[1]);
      int id = String.parseInt(args[2]);

      // We assgin the values into `courseStudent`
      courseStudent.setName(name);
      courseStudent.setAge(age);
      courseStudent.setID(id);

      courseStudent.printAll();
      System.out.println(", ID: " + courseStudent.getID());
```

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help and the resources. I figured it was a simple oversight.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add set values so you don’t get null and 0 as output.
The correct answer is:

```
courseStudent.setID(9999);
courseStudent.setName(“Smith”);
courseStudent.setAge(20);
courseStudent.printAll();
System.out.print(“, ID: “ + courseStudent.getID());
System.out.println(“”);
```